# can no longer select physical iPad device for Xamarin iOS app with Visual Studio running on Windows 10

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

XCODE IS 10.0
VS IS 15.8.7

I get error below when I try to debug from Visual Studio 2017 Pro running on my Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, through MacBook 10.13.6 to iPad 12.0.1

This was working for weeks.  A couple days ago, I started getting this error every time.
Tried upgrading VS.
Restart Windows, of course.

[image]

ABOUT MY  VISUAL STUDIO

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 
Version 15.8.7
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.8.7+28010.2046
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03056

Installed Version: Professional

Visual C++ 2017   00370-10200-52153-AA071
Microsoft Visual C++ 2017

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   8.13.10627.1
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.8.05085.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017

ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   15.8.31590
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017   5.2.60618.0
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   15.8.05023.0
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   15.8.05023.0
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

C# Tools   2.9.0-beta8-63208-01
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Extensibility Message Bus   1.1.49 (remotes/origin/d15-8@ee674f3)
Provides common messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.

JavaScript Language Service   2.0
JavaScript Language Service

JavaScript Project System   2.0
JavaScript Project System

Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 - v2.9.10730.2

Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.4
Simplifying the configuration of Azure DevOps pipelines from within the Visual Studio IDE.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft Library Manager   1.0
Install client-side libraries easily to any web project

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards   1.0
Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1
Develop, run, validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5 your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL + F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.

Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package

MLGen Package Extension   1.0
MLGen Package Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   4.11.11-pre (8fb558f)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

NuGet Package Manager   4.6.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
ProjectServicesPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

ResourcePackage Extension   1.0
ResourcePackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

ResourcePackage Extension   1.0
ResourcePackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.61808.07020
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Test Adapter for Boost.Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Boost.Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

Test Adapter for Google Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Google Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

TypeScript Tools   15.8.20822.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   2.9.0-beta8-63208-01
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools 10.2 for F# 4.5   15.8.0.0.  Commit Hash: 55a3dc3231c95c77f81ee53f7d29152029da7408.
Microsoft Visual F# Tools 10.2 for F# 4.5

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Tools for CMake   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for CMake

Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers

Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   15.0.28010.2046
The Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build a single universal app experience that can reach every device running Windows 10: phone, tablet, PC, and more. It includes the Microsoft Windows 10 Software Development Kit.

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Mac Extension for Visual Studio

Xamarin   4.11.0.776 (d15-8@1ae9b59d7)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   4.15.9 (d000f568b)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   1.1.116 (9619170)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   9.0.0.19 (HEAD/a8a3b0ec7)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   12.0.0.15 (84552a4)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
```

Comment: Maybe your network have a problem,when i have this problem.I try this way to solve it. **First** Disconnect to your Mac,**Second** RePair to Your Mac. Then you can see the iPad simulator in your tool bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION was to plug the iPad in to the Mac.
It had been disconnected.